# ARM templates more lines

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have an issue with ARM templates where, when there is an error, it will always say **line 1**.

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource at line '1' and column '3276'
is not valid: The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location. Please see
https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details..
```

My ARM template clearly has more lines than 1. This makes troubleshooting very hard. How do I save the file so that is has more lines when an error occures??

#### Additional information

Deploy method: YAML (Azure DevOps)

```yaml
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: ***
      subscriptionId: ***
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: ***
      location: 'West Europe'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: 'pipelines/azuredeploy.json'
      csmParametersFile: 'pipelines/azuredeploy.parameters.json'
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      deploymentName: 'AzureDeployment-$(fullversion)'
```

- Encoding used: UTF-8
- End of line sequence: CRLF

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think whatever you're using to deploy (or whatever AzDO is using) is minifying the template - if you deploy from PowerShell do you get the same error? (I think CLI minifies)

Comment: Thank you @bmoore-msft, I believe you are right. When I use the deploy script provided by the Visual Studio Azure Resources template I do get the corresponding lines: _"The template resource 'location' at line '26' and column '21' is not valid"_. I think I will use the PowerShell instead of the DevOps Tasks. I would love that Microsoft would provide an options to not minify the template when using the DevOps task.

Comment: I think the minification is being covered here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13159 - feel free to +1 it ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you do not use the Azure ARM template function `reference` in the right location. In fact, the `reference` function just can be used in the properties of a resource definition and the outputs section of a template or deployment. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#valid-uses-1)

Besides, you can use the Powershell command `Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment -debug` to debug your ARM template.

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you for your response, this is however not the question. I know what is the issue about the `reference` is, and fixed it is. The problem is that when an exception occurs, it is always saying **line 1**.